# Mysql Geo Spatial Search returns strange results

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial

I am currently trying to setup a spatial search in Mysql and PHP. For this I use the haversin formula that I found in the following link:

http://www.notaires.fr/sites/default/files/geo_searchjkkjkj_0.pdf

At the moment for test purposes I use the direct query (slowest approach of course) but it acts really strange.

From one of my database entries I copy the latitude and longitude information for and use them for test purposes but I still get an empty result back. So I removed the having statement to look what distance actually comes out as a result for my images and it is 4098.9334608610825 for the database entry where I took the coordinates from.

I am using the exact formula that is shown on slide 8 (of course I adapted the field names and table name to my database) in the powerpoint of the link but I just keep getting these strange results.

Any idea or suggestions how I can solve this? Or maybe there are even much better ways to do the spatial search if so, please let me know (just not sphinx for now because I can't install anything like that on my servers at the moment as I'm not the owner)

[image]

Here you can see the picture with my results. The first result is the database entry where I took my coordinates from.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select (acos(sin(radians(@orig_lat)) * sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(radians(@orig_lat)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(@orig_lon))) * 6378) as dist
```

Think I writed it correctly

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. Actually this one returns a dist of 6608.442268294232 :-/ I have no idea what's going wrong :-(

Comment: That formula works for me, can be checked an example in the following url: http://www.suhogar.info/residencias/4-303/Almeria/Almeria  Could it be an incorrect value of orig_lat or orig_lan what could be causing the error?

Comment: orig_lat: 135.674151 orig_long: 34.833236
this is what I use for orig_lat and orig_long which are the coordinates in the format that the iOS App supports it to my Rest api for storing it

Comment: Further research took me to this sentence: Latitude: Valid range is -90 to +90 Maybe you should use some mod operator? like converting 135 => 45 or -45

Comment: ok looks like iOS is serving the coordinates in another format, I'll try to find a way to convert this thank you :-)

Comment: by taking a closer look at it I found out that longitude is between -180 and 180 so maybe I save them the wrong way and save the longitude in the latitude field and the other way around

Comment: About to suggest the same :P try this web http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml will let you calculate the distance, change those values and see if the result matches what you expect

Comment: thank you very much :-)

looks like the people in the powerpoint I added the link to are also confused because they use @orig_lat=121.97 so I got confused and entered the wrong coordinates, I store everything the right way actually and just made a mistake when setting these variables :-)

Comment: You may have your latitude and longitude swapped.  It seems the location you have provided is in Hirakata in Osaka Prefecture. If that is true, then you definitely should exchange lat and long. If it's near Adelaide, Australia, you also need to make the sign on your latitude negative.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different version of the spherical cosine law formula. It is this for MySQL:

```
  DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(lat1))
             * COS(RADIANS(lat2))
             * COS(RADIANS(long1 - long2))
             + SIN(RADIANS(lat1))
             * SIN(RADIANS(lat2)))) AS distance_in_degrees
```

You can then convert these degrees to km. Multiply by 111.045 to do that.

If you need a more numerically stable version of the great circle distance computation (you probably don't), try the Vincenty formula:

```
DEGREES(
  ATAN2(
    SQRT(
    POW(COS(RADIANS(lat2))*SIN(RADIANS(lon2-lon1)),2) +
    POW(COS(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2)) -
         (SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2)) *
          COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))) ,2)),
  SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2)) +
  COS(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))))
```

It, too, returns the distance in degrees.

This material is written up here.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Comment: Thank you very much :-)
I tried it out but the result in kilometers is still 6592.286252411423 even for the entry where I used the latitude and longitude from :-/ the coordinates that are stored are stored in the format that iOS gives it back if you use the CLLocationManager so for my entry that I try out that would be:
latitude: 135.674151 longitude: 34.833236
If that is of any help